# Getting Null Error When Running Flutter Tests

Tags: flutter, dart, automated-tests, clean-architecture

Firstly for context I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPkWX8xFthE&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iYGE_khpXRdJkJEp9WOech&index=2

However, I think there are some updates to flutter since this was released which is causing some issues. I'm getting this error while running the test and I'm not sure where to look for a solution:

`type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Either<Failure, NumberTrivia>>`

Here is the code of my test:

```dart
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:flutter_clean_code/features/number_trivia/domain/entities/number_trivia.dart';
import 'package:flutter_clean_code/features/number_trivia/domain/repositories/number_trivia_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter_clean_code/features/number_trivia/domain/use_cases/get_concrete_number_trivia.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockNumberTriviaRepository extends Mock
    implements NumberTriviaRepository {}

void main() {
  late GetConcreteNumberTrivia usecase;
  late MockNumberTriviaRepository mockNumberTriviaRepository;

  setUp(() {
    mockNumberTriviaRepository = MockNumberTriviaRepository();
    usecase = GetConcreteNumberTrivia(mockNumberTriviaRepository);
  });

  const tNumber = 1;
  const tNumberTrivia = NumberTrivia(number: 1, text: 'test trivia');

  test(
    'should get trivia for the number from the repository',
    () async {
      // arrange
      when(mockNumberTriviaRepository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(1))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => const Right(tNumberTrivia));
      // act
      final result = await usecase.execute(number: tNumber);
      // assert
      expect(result, const Right(tNumberTrivia));
      verify(mockNumberTriviaRepository.getConcreteNumberTrivia(tNumber));
      verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockNumberTriviaRepository);
    },
  );
}
```

Where should I be looking to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Mitchell

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems as though the fault was with the package `mockito` I've switched to `mocktail` and that is working correctly with nearly identical code.